# Finding all cells that have been filled with any color and highlighting corresponding column headers in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

**My problem:**

I've made a large (2,000 line) macro that runs on our company's template and fixes some common issues  and highlights other issues we have prior to importing. The template file always has 150 columns and is in most instances 15,000+ rows (sometimes even over 30,000). The macro works well, highlighting all the cells that contain errors according to our data rules, but with a file with so many columns and rows I thought it'd be convenient to add a snippet to my macro that would have it find all of the cells that have been highlighted and then highlight the column headers of the columns that contain those highlighted cells.

**Methods I've found while searching for a solution:**

- [SpecialCells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx)`xlCellTypeAllFormatConditions` only works for conditional formatting, so that isn't a plausible method for my situation
- Rick Rothstein's UDF from [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-customize/vba-code-to-identify-if-a-row-has-any-colored/cbc59a54-4b6b-43e4-9218-ae5db59255aa?auth=1)

  ```
  Sub FindYellowCells()
    Dim YellowCell As Range, FirstAddress As String
    Const IndicatorColumn As String = "AK"
    Columns(IndicatorColumn).ClearContents
    '   The next code line sets the search for Yellow color... the next line after it (commented out) searches
    '   for the ColorIndex 6 (which is usually yellow), so use whichever code line is applicable to your situation
    Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    'Application.FindFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Set YellowCell = Cells.Find("*", After:=Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count), SearchFormat:=True)
    If Not YellowCell Is Nothing Then
      FirstAddress = YellowCell.Address
      Do
        Cells(YellowCell.Row, IndicatorColumn).Value = "X"
        Set YellowCell = Cells.Find("*", After:=YellowCell, SearchFormat:=True)
        If YellowCell Is Nothing Then Exit Do
      Loop While FirstAddress <> YellowCell.Address
    End If
  End Sub
  ```

  This would be perfect with a few tweaks, except our files can have multiple colorfills. Since our template is so large I've learned that it takes quite some time to run one instance of `Find` to find just one colorfill in the `UsedRange`.
- Using filtering, maybe cycling through all the columns and checking each if they contain any cell that has any colorfill. Would that be any faster though?

**So, my question:**

1. How could I accomplish finding all columns that contain *any* colorfilled cells? More specifically, what would be the most efficient (fastest) way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not record the cells that are highlighted when you highlight them? That would be more efficient then doing a linear search over hundreds of thousands of cells.

Comment: That is true, but the only reason I haven't turned to that yet is because it would require editing about 15 sub routines and finding each instance where a cell would r highlighted. So, yes it is an option/solution, I'm just trying to see if there were a quicker way before I turn to that.

Comment: You could create a single sub to do the recording (perhaps to a string in the names collection) and just add calls to that sub to locations which can be easily located by a search

Comment: Could you provide an example? I want to make sure I'm following you correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most performant solution would be to search using recursion by half-interval.
It takes less than 5 seconds to tag the columns from a worksheet with 150 columns and 30000 rows.

The code to search for a specific color:

```
Sub TagColumns()
  Dim headers As Range, body As Range, col As Long, found As Boolean

  ' define the columns for the headers and body
  Set headers = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Columns
  Set body = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1).Columns

  ' iterate each column
  For col = 1 To headers.Count

    ' search for the yellow color in the column of the body
    found = HasColor(body(col), vbYellow)

    ' set the header to red if found, green otherwise
    headers(col).Interior.color = IIf(found, vbRed, vbGreen)
  Next

End Sub

Public Function HasColor(rg As Range, color As Long) As Boolean
  If rg.DisplayFormat.Interior.color = color Then
    HasColor = True
  ElseIf VBA.IsNull(rg.DisplayFormat.Interior.colorIndex) Then
    ' The color index is null so there is more than one color in the range
    Dim midrow&
    midrow = rg.Rows.Count \ 2
    If HasColor(rg.Resize(midrow), color) Then
      HasColor = True
    ElseIf HasColor(rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - midrow).Offset(midrow), color) Then
      HasColor = True
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

And to search for any color:

```
Sub TagColumns()
  Dim headers As Range, body As Range, col As Long, found As Boolean

  ' define the columns for the headers and body
  Set headers = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Columns
  Set body = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1).Columns

  ' iterate each column
  For col = 1 To headers.Count

    ' search for any color in the column of the body
    found = VBA.IsNull(body(col).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex)

    ' set the header to red if found, green otherwise
    headers(col).Interior.color = IIf(found, vbRed, vbGreen)
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a brilliant solution. I just have two questions though. How could this be modified so it would search for *any* color or any cell that isn't `vbNull`? Second, is your last comment accurate? I would think if it were `vbNull` that it would mean there weren't any colors in that range. Maybe you could help try to clear that up (explain that) for me?

Comment: Just another comment to make sure you saw my first one since I know you were editing while I posted

Comment: I've updated the response to search for any color. And yes it's accurate, the colorIndex is Null when there is more than 1 color and -4142 for the default color.

Comment: Thanks for the updated solution and explanation! I'll test this code tomorrow morning and mark this as the answer once I see it working.

Comment: It works perfectly! And it's so efficient/fast. Thanks so much for sharing this method with me!

Comment: fine and fast solution. just two warnings. The first being you have to adjust either `rowCount =...` or `.Resize(rowCount)` since as they are now set they also consider the first row just below the `UsedRange` last one. Most probably it'll not be colorfilled but should it (accidentally) be it'd result in wrong header coloring. The second being that it's assumed data cells begin at column 1 and header row index is 1. Should your header not begin at cell A1 then it'd miss some cell and or column checking. Finally it can be made quite faster (if needed!: I try and edit the post with improvement)

Comment: Since our company adheres to strict data rules those two issues/limitations won't be of concern in my situation. Also, @florentbr I have a simple and (probably) silly follow-up question. If I've filled cells by using `.Interior.Color` throughout my code will this still pick those cell colors up? The reason I ask is because I notice it's looking for `.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex`, not `.Color`. I'm just niave in knowing whether or not `.Color` properties will yield a `.ColorIndex`. Sorry *blush*

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder, yes the .Interior.ColorIndex is updated when the .Interior.Color is assigned either manually, by a format condition or by code.

Comment: Great, then this is the perfect solution for me. Thanks for helping clear that up for me

Answer (score 3):

Before:

[image]

Running this short macro:

```
Sub FindingColor()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r As Range
    Dim nFirstColumn As Long, nLastColumn As Long, ic As Long

    Set r1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    nLastColumn = r1.Columns.Count + r1.Column - 1
    nFirstColumn = r1.Column

    For ic = nFirstColumn To nLastColumn
        Set r2 = Intersect(r1, Columns(ic))
        For Each r In r2
            If r.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
                r2(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
                Exit For
            End If
        Next r
    Next ic

End Sub
```

produces:

[image]

I just don't know about the speed issue.  If the colored cells are near the top of the column, the code will run super fast; if the colored cells are missing or near the bottom of the column, not so much.

**EDIT#1:**

Please note that my code will not find cells colored conditionally.

Comment: If you examined the [Range.DisplayFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814.aspx), you should be able to pick up manually colored and CF colored cells in one pass. e.g. `If r.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then`

Comment: @Jeeped  Sadly I am still using *Excel 2007/Windows7*

Comment: @Jeeped  I put the restriction in **EDIT#1**

Comment: This is a solution, but I believe it would be quite slow for my situation as the highlights can be scattered about at the top, middle, and/or bottom. Also, @Jeeped I'm only looking to find colors that are not filled from conditional formatting.

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder  As soon as my code finds the first colored cell in a column, it immediately colors the header and skips to the next column.

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder  Only an experiment can determine if the code is "fast enough."

Comment: You're right, I might just be thinking about how in the past iterating through that many rows 150 times took awhile. But, then again I guess it depends on what's done in the loop. You do have a point that this might be quicker since as soon as it/if finds a highlighted cell it will move on to the next row. I'll test it out and see how it fairs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) actually has three potential optional [xlRangeValueDataType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837565.aspx) parameters. The default is **xlRangeValueDefault** and that is all (by omission) most anyone ever uses.

The **xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet** option retrieves an XML data block which describes many of the properties that the cell maintains. A cell with no [Range.Interior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836210.aspx) property beyond xlAutomatic will have the following XML element,

```
<Interior/>
```

... while a cell with an [.Interior.Color](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840499.aspx) property will have the following XML element,

```
<Interior ss:Color="#FF0000" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
```

It's been well established that dumping a worksheet's values into a variant array and processing in-memory is substantially quicker than looping through cells so retrieving the `.Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet)` and performing an [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on the single blob of XML data should prove much faster.

```
Sub filledOrNot()
    Dim c As Long, r As Long, vCLRs As String

    appTGGL bTGGL:=False

    With Worksheets("30Kdata")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    vCLRs = .Columns(c).Cells.Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet)
                    If CBool(InStr(1, vCLRs, "<Interior ss:Color=", vbBinaryCompare)) Then _
                        .Cells(0, c).Interior.Color = 49407
                Next c
            End With
        End With
        Debug.Print Len(vCLRs)
    End With

    appTGGL

End Sub

Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
        .EnableEvents = bTGGL
        .DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
        .AutoRecover.Enabled = bTGGL   'no interruptions with an auto-save
        .Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .StatusBar = vbNullString
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer
End Sub
```

I ran this against 30K rows by 26 columns. While each column was examined, I had only seeded every third column with an .Interior.Color property somewhere randomly within the 30K rows. It took about a minute and a half.

Each column of 30K rows produced an XML record that was almost 3Mbs in size; a length of 2,970,862 was typical. Once read into a variable, it was searched for the fingerprint of a set interior fill.

[image: isitfilled]

Discarding the read into the string type var and performing the InStr directly on the .Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet) actually improved the time by about two seconds.

Comment: This is very clever. I had no idea that the `Range.Value` property had an optional parameter. That still takes a bit longer than I'd like though :(

Comment: This was an intellectual exercise. What you need is a 'helper' sub that will get the cell, worksheet and color passed to it every time your other 15 routines want to color a cell. The 'helper' will log the cell, create a hyperlink to the cell on the correct worksheet and color it. Later when you want to correct the errors you can just click on the log hyperlink and go directly to the rogue value.

Answer (score 1):

My proposal using `AutoFilter` method of `Range` object

it runs quite fast

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterByFillColor()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim headerRng As Range
Dim iCol As Long, RGBColor As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HeadersToColor") '<== set it to your actual name of the data worksheet
Set headerRng = ws.Range("headers") '<== I set a named range "headers" in my test sheet addressing the cells that cointains all headers. but you may use explicit address ie: 'ws.Range("B2:EU150")' for a 150 columns header range
RGBColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
headerRng.Interior.Color = vbGreen
With headerRng.CurrentRegion
    For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
        .AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:=RGBColor, Operator:=xlFilterNoFill
        If .Columns(iCol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count < .Rows.Count Then headerRng(iCol).Interior.Color = vbRed
        .AutoFilter
    Next iCol
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```