# VBA find columns which contains cells with specify color, then copy those columns to other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

i have some data in range A1 to EA6000 in sheet "RB". In that range in row 30 some cells with specify date i marked on VBgreen color. Now i need VBA to find columns which contain cells with VBgreen, copy those columns and paste one by one to sheet "Plan" starting from column AA, then Ab etc. (AA+1) .

I tried with that code but faied....

```vb
    Sub CopyColumnsWithGreenCells()
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim firstEmptyColumn As Integer
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RB")
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("plan")
    Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("AA:EA")
    firstEmptyColumn = targetSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    For i = 1 To sourceRange.Columns.Count
        For j = 1 To sourceRange.Rows.Count
            If sourceRange.Cells(j, i).Interior.Color = vbGreen Then
                Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range(targetSheet.Cells(1, firstEmptyColumn), targetSheet.Cells(sourceRange.Rows.Count, firstEmptyColumn))
                sourceRange.Columns(i).Copy
                targetRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                firstEmptyColumn = firstEmptyColumn + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975076/finding-all-cells-that-have-been-filled-with-any-color-and-highlighting-correspo

Comment: "failed" doesn't tell us much about the problem you're having with this code.  What does it do (or not do) when you run it and how is that different from what you want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```vb
Sub CopyColumnsWithGreenCells()
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim sourceRange As Range, targetRange As Range
    Dim col As Range, f As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set targetRange = wb.Sheets("plan").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
    
    Application.FindFormat.Clear                     'reset FindFormat
    Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = vbGreen  'background color
    
    For Each col In wb.Sheets("RB").Range("AA:EA").Columns
        Set f = col.Find(what:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchFormat:=True)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then 'got a match?
            targetRange.Resize(col.Rows.Count, col.Columns.Count).Value = col.Value
            Set targetRange = targetRange.Offset(0, 1) 'next destination
        End If
    Next col
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
End Sub
```